# Black zones when hiding / showing softkeyboard with a surfaceview in the layout

Tags: java, android

I have simplified the problem for explain it easily: The initial layout of my test is:

[image]

And when I execute it (with only a setContentView call in the activity) it shows the following layout when I open the soft keyboard for the input:

[image]

but when I hide the keyboard its behaviour is a little buggy Lefting this image in the screen (a black rectangle in the slot where the surfaceview was):

[image]

Tried in the emulator with the same result.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It is a bug that can be solved with

`theSurfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);` or `android:background="#00000000"` at the XML

Comment: Seriously - like seriously :D Thank you for this.